# How to get links from a Google Action to appear in the Google Home App?

Tags: actions-on-google

How can links to URLs be sent from a Google Action to the Google Home App? I'm referring to the blue text boxes that appear on the Discover tab of the Google Home App.

For example, if someone uses the Google Home smart speaker to search for a recipe, if the result is from the Food Network, a link to the full recipe URL will appear in the app.

I'm using API.AI to build the action, with the node.js library provided by Google. I've successfully built rich media cards that contain the link, and they appear in the Google Actions simulator and on the Google Pixel platform -- but nothing appears in the Google Home App.

Thank you!
[Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL948.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Actions SDK currently only supports the display of cards as part of the action user interface on devices with screens.

Comment: Thanks, Leon. I'm referring to the Google Home Android App, which does display links related to voice-only conversations with the Google Home speaker. For example, if you say "Ok Google, give me a recipe for preparing snap peas" you'll get a response from the Food Network. It tells you to look on the Google Home App for more information. And then if you open the app at your leisure, you will see a blue text box on the Discover tab that has the link and title. That's what I'm trying to implement. Thanks again.

Comment: The Actions SDK does not support the Google Home app integration.

Comment: There clearly is a method for doing this, since you get exactly that behaviour if you request a recipe on the Google Home speaker and get a result from the Food Network. See the screen capture I added to the original post: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL948.png